# Exception handler doesn't use the value in @ResponseStatus

Tags: java, spring

I have the following controller advice to handle the exceptions within my app globally:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandlingController {

      // Convert a predefined exception to an HTTP Status code
      @ResponseStatus(value=HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)  // 400
      @ExceptionHandler(ConstraintViolationException.class)
      public void ConstraintViolationExceptionHandler() {
          //Nothing to do
      }
}
```

The code below is the controller, which tries to save an object to the db (in the service layer). The class that object belongs to, has annotations that fail.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void create(@RequestBody CustomUserDetails user, HttpServletResponse response) {
    logger.debug("User signup attempt with username: " + username);
    userDetailsServices.saveIfNotExists(user);
}
```

I expect the client to receive a 400 response when ConstraintViolationException is thrown.

When the method returns `void` , no response is returned. When I change it `String` and return a random text, I get 404 response back.

```
{
  "timestamp": 1495489172770,
  "status": 404,
  "error": "Not Found",
  "exception": "javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException",
  "message": "Validation failed for classes [security.model.CustomUserDetails] during persist time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]\nList of constraint violations:[\n\tConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='must match \"^(?!.*\\..*\\..*)[A-Za-z]([A-Za-z0-9.]*[A-Za-z0-9]){8,15}$\"', propertyPath=username, rootBeanClass=class com.boot.cut_costs.security.model.CustomUserDetails, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.Pattern.message}'}\n]",
  "path": "/signup"
}
```

How can I make this return a simple BAD REQUEST message as it is defined for the `@ExceptionHandler`.

**Note**: `ConstraintViolationExceptionHandler` is hit!

Comment: Could you post your controller including annotations?

Comment: I added the controller code.

Comment: You most likely get a 500 because spring assumes when a `@Controller` annotated class has a method with `@RequestMapping` returning a String, that this String is the name of the view (and the failing view lookup results is a 500 error). Are you trying to build a rest endpoint?

Comment: Yes, I am. I made a mistake. 404 is returned. I updated the post.

Comment: does ConstraintViolationExceptionHandler really do nothing? Seems like you haven't provided everything. Presumably you are mapping the an exception to some object and returning it which gets serialized into the json you provided

Comment: It really does nothing. but when I put a dummy code inside `ConstraintViolationExceptionHandler` method, it gets hit.

Comment: have you tried debugging that?, i don't think request is mapping to `ConstraintViolationExceptionHandler`